# Find how many point can be reach?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, computational-geometry

**Input:**

- A set of points (integer coordinates) (2D space)
- A set of integer which determine the limit

**Output:**

- For each `limit` in the set, output how many points can be reached from first points.
- Point `A` can reach to `B` iff `AB <= limit`

**My current solution:**

- Calculate all distance between every points
- Sort them
- For each limit, use DFS to count how many points are there

**The question:**

For a large set of limit, the program will run slowly (I need to re-DFS for each query). What algorithm / data structure can I use for better performance?

Comment: Let me edit the question to make it more clear;

The first point is the first points of the set input

Comment: Is there only one first point? Or are there many first points? If there is only one first point, you can answer all the queries in log N time.

Comment: Only one first point, let call it A

A can't reach to C directly, but if A can reach to B and B can reach to C then A can reach to C also, I don't think do it in log N is possible

Comment: What prevents you from computing all distances from A to every other point just once, and storing them? Also this has nothing to do with computational geometry, it's **THE** classical graph theory problem. [Relevant info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Comment: my current solution calculate all distance between every points and store them, but I still run slowly for a large set of limit

Comment: You don't need to calculate distances between every pair of points, just between A and all other points. Look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) that does just that and is very fast.

Comment: Are your points 'with integer coordinates' spreaded over a number axis (a line), ie. each point is identified as an integer number? Over are they on a plane (integer numbers pairs? Or 5-dimensional space...?

Comment: @CiaPan in 2D plane, sorry, EDITED

Comment: @n.m. How can it work ? I think it is wrong.

Comment: See Wikipedia article on a [Euclidean minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree), section 'Algorithms for computing EMSTs in two dimensions'.

Answer (score 1):

Store all pairs in array, sorted by distance.
Instead of DFS, execute [union-find algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) on left (smaller) part of array. You will get disjoint (sometimes joint) forest, where rank of the component containing the first point is what you want.

Note that rank is monotonically increases with distance increase.

Now walk through all array left to right, and write down reached distance to Dist array, and reached rank of the first component to Rank array.

Now for every limit query find this value position index in Dist array (with binary search) and get corresponding value from Rank array - complexity per one query is
O(log(n^2))=**O(log(n))**

Answer (score 0):

Having integer coordinates doesn't help much when you consider Euclidean distances: points (0,0) and (1,1) are sqrt(2) apart, which is not integer and not even rational. Luckily you don't have to do any arithmetics on the distances, just comparing them, so you can store and compare integer squares of distances.

The best way I can see (but I'm not an expert in this kind of problems!) is to build a minimum spanning tree (See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814000/find-how-many-point-can-be-reach#comment34869568_22814000)), then cut it in parts: for each given limit remove branches which are longer than that limit, then identify connected components ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29)) remaining – those are your "reachable subsets".

If you start from the largest limit and proceed to the minimum, you can do the task iteratively: every branch removal will split the component to which the branch belongs into two parts, but no other component will be affected. That may simplify the work, provided the data structure allows to associate branches and subgraphs effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a variation of Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest path finding, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm , you can get away with `O(n*log(n))`. This will label all points with their distance from the one starting point. Then you simply sort (`O(n*log(n))`) and output them (`O(n*l)` for a naive aproach; if you have many limits, then sort them first and you end up with `O(n*log(n) + l*log(l))`).